# Writing to Stackdriver can be slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Lately, our team is *occasionally* experiencing really slow response when *writing* log messages to Stackdriver. We're using the .NET SDK Google.Cloud.Logging.V2 version 2.3.0 library. Measurement is done using `Stopwatch` before and after the call to the logging method. Our microservices are deployed in a GCP Kubernetes cluster.

Usually, the API takes about 150-300ms to respond when sending a message but there are exceptional cases where it can take between 1-18 seconds for the `LoggingServiceV2Client.WriteLogEntriesAsync()` to respond. Whilst the method takes an array of log entries we're only sending one entry at a time.

Is there anything that can affect the *write-speed*? We do log a lot and often so the logName `Global` is getting huge. I haven't been able to find any information about Stackdriver performance.

We're now experimenting with console logging and Google's implementation of ILogger and they seem to be much faster though I'm not sure if it's because we're writing to a different logName.

Comment: The first step is to **not** write one log entry at a time. To answer your question requires more information such as the region, minimum reproducible example that reproduces the problem, etc.

Comment: Please provide more information about your setup for reproduction purposes.